# Why does cron silently fail to run sudo stuff in my script?

Tags: sudo, cron

I have a script run from a non-privileged users' crontab that invokes some commands using `sudo`. Except it doesn't. The script runs fine but the sudo'ed commands silently fail.

- The script runs perfectly from a shell as the user in question.
- Sudo does not require a password. The user in question has `(root) NOPASSWD: ALL` access granted in `/etc/sudoers`.
- Cron is running and executing the script. Adding a simple `date > /tmp/log` produces output at the right time.
- It's not a permissions problem. Again the script does get executed, just not the sudo'ed commands.
- It's not a path problem. Running `env` from inside the script being run shows the correct `$PATH` variable that includes the path to sudo. Running it using a full path doesn't help. The command being executed is being given the full path name.
- Trying to capture the output of the sudo command including STDERR doesn't show anything useful. Adding `sudo echo test 2>&1 > /tmp/log` to the script produces a blank log.
- The sudo binary itself executes fine and recognizes that it has permissions even when run from cron inside the script. Adding `sudo -l > /tmp/log` to the script produces the output:

  > User ec2-user may run the following commands on this host:
  >   (root) NOPASSWD: ALL

Examining the exit code of the command using `$?` shows it is returning an error (exit code: `1`), but no error seems to be produced. A command as simple as `/usr/bin/sudo /bin/echo test` returns the same error code.

**What else could be going on?**

This is a recently created virtual machine running the latest Amazon Linux AMI. The crontab belongs to the user `ec2-user` and the sudoers file is the distribution default.

Comment: I was going to talk about a solution but then I read `The user in question has (root) NOPASSWD: ALL access granted in /etc/sudoers` and my brain started screaming too loud to keep reading.

Comment: @Shadur: Talk to the hand. That isn't my way of setting up a machine either, but these machines come this way out of the box. Even through the machine is yours, you don't get a root password, your key as the owner of the box goes into the ec2-user account which has (as noted) full sudo access. You don't get a password for ec2-user either unless you set one, it's a key only login.

Comment: Then the first thing I'd recommend you do is set up a separate user with restricted `sudo` rights /only/ for the commands you need in the script and disabling their login ability completely.

Comment: if you have root, and you want the cron job to run as root, then why put it in ec2-user's crontab?  wouldn't root's crontab be more appropriate?  or /etc/crontab?

Comment: @CraigSanders: I don't want the cron job run as root, in fact most of it should be run as a user. The question is not about running a job as root, but about a script having specially access to one function through sudo.

Comment: @Shadur: I would do that in a heartbeat if it was a desktop system or even a multi-use server that was ever going to get logged into, but honestly considering the entire system is instantiated, configured, run and administered through a one time setup script and then shut off, only to have a new one launched using the same script, I don't think it makes a dime of difference whether whether I isolate the cron job from the admin user or not.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`sudo` has some special options in its permissions file, one of which allows a restriction on its usage to shells that are are running inside a `TTY`, which `cron` is not.

Some distros including the Amazon Linux AMI have this enabled by default. The `/etc/sudoers` file will look something like this:

```
# Disable "ssh hostname sudo <cmd>", because it will show the password in clear.
#         You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo <cmd>".
#
Defaults    requiretty

#
# Refuse to run if unable to disable echo on the tty. This setting should also be
# changed in order to be able to use sudo without a tty. See requiretty above.
#
Defaults   !visiblepw
```

If you had captured output to `STDERR` at the level of the shell script rather than the sudo command itself, you would have seem a message something like this:

> sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

The solution is to allow sudo to execute in non `TTY` environments either by removing or commenting out these options:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
#Defaults   !visiblepw
```

Comment: I can confirm that CentOS does have these restrictions in place.

Comment: It looks like requiretty was added in CentOS 7, so while this wasn't required with CentOS 6, it is with CentOS 7+. In my experience, sudo commands from the cron work on CentOS 6 even if the `Defaults   !visiblepw` is turned on/not commented out.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, and probably no longer of interest to the OP, but for others who may be struggling with the use of `sudo` in a `user crontab`, here's a potential solution:

Instead of using `sudo` in a `user crontab`, use the `root crontab`:

```bsh
$ sudo crontab -e
```

In *some* systems - depending on how `sudo` is configured - using `sudo` in a `user crontab` will actually work (e.g. Raspberry Pi OS). However, using the `root crontab` is a more portable approach; it also eliminates the need to use `sudo` to run any command or script. So, if you used `sudo mount 'blah, blah'` in a `user crontab`, it becomes `mount 'blah, blah'` in the `root crontab`.

If you don't know what the environment is for jobs run under `cron`, you can ask `cron` to tell you by adding this entry to the `root crontab` (`sudo crontab -e`):

```
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/printenv > /home/user_me/cronenvironment_sudo.txt 2>&1
```

Change `user_me` to an actual username on your system, and see the [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) for help with the schedule.

And finally, see this Q&A for how to [change the environment in `cron`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use).