# Shell script executed with cron results in different size file than executed manually

Tags: shell-script, rhel, cron, mysql

I have a RHEL server that I am running a MySQL database on.  I have a Bash script that executes `mysqldump` that creates a backup file.  The backup file created when executing the script directly in Bash is 754259 bytes in size.  If the same script is run via cron, it's only 20 bytes in size.

As far as I know, cron is running with the same user context that I use when logged in to run the script manually.  However, given the size differential, that does not appear to be true.

Why are the file sizes different when running the same script?

The shell script contents:

```
backup_path=/var/custom/db_backups
configFile=/var/custom/auth.cnf
db_name=[db_name]
date=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")

sudo /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$configFile $db_name | gzip -9  > $backup_path/$db_name-$date.sql.gz
```

To edit cron:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

cron file contents:

```
12 21 * * * /var/custom/maint_plan
```

This executes the script daily at 9:13 PM.

Comment: Can you post the exact mysqldump command from the script, or at best the full script itself?

Comment: pls post the cron entry

Comment: You should probably remove `sudo` from the script: you are running it from root's crontab anyway, and sudo may not like running without a tty - see [Why does cron silently fail to run sudo stuff in my script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script)

Comment: Revise cron file contents so that you record stdout+stderr "12 21 * * * /var/custom/maint_plan >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1".  Also, would be good practice to add a #!/bin/bash to the start of your script.

Comment: There was surely an error message to tell you what is wrong. Error messages from cron jobs are sent over local email. Make sure that you have local email set up and that you read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysqldump` command returns nothing, which is piped trough `gzip` and ends in an empty gzip file. See:

```
$ echo -n "" | gzip -9  > test.gz
$ stat -c %s test.gz
20
```

This results in a file with size 20 bytes. So the problem is the `mysqldump` command. Since it's root's crontab the script runs with root priviledges. `sudo` is not necessary. Use it without `sudo`. Just:

```
/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$configFile $db_name | gzip -9  > $backup_path/$db_name-$date.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

The script run via cron is failing. 20 bytes is the size of an empty MySQL dump.

Comment: Is there a log that I can inspect to determine the issue?

Comment: The script executes properly when run manually.  If it were a variable issue, would it not fail regardless of execution originator?

Comment: I mean that arguments aren't passed correctly to the script when run via cron. Please post the content of your crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

The environment that cron runs scripts in is very limited. It may not be finding all of the required programs. Capture the environment variables of the shell in which you get a good dump and carry that over to your cron script.